# How to achieve nested spinner?

Tags: android

I have requirement for filtering category type -> category -> products. For this I have to use nested spinner as we have in eclipse package explorer.

How can I achieve?

Comment: I don't understand exactly your question. If you provide me a good explication maybe I could help you.

Comment: I need nested spinner for filtering in my project. Take example of android project. projectname -> src -> activity.java. how can i achive this hierarchy?

Comment: not sure but `ExpandableListView` may solve your problem for 1 level.

Comment: @Ketan I tried with expandable list view, but I need more than 3 inner levels. where as in Expandable list view we can do only for 2 levels.

Comment: this may help you http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/best-way-of-representing-hierarchical-data-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, I am not sure if you are looking for something like that. I have 2 spinner, when the user select a item from brandspinner, the modelspinner is setted with all the products of this brand.

```
private Spinner brandSpinner;
private Spinner modelSpinner;

brandSpinner = (Spinner)root.findViewById(R.id.brand_spinner);      
modelSpinner = (Spinner)root.findViewById(R.id.model_spinner);


brandsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BrandItem>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ArrayListWithBrands);

//I am not sure if it is needed:                                                
brandsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

brandSpinner.setAdapter(brandsAdapter);

brandSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {

        //Harcoding Brands:
        BrandItem brand = brandsArrHarcode.get(pos);    

        final ArrayList<String> modelsArr = brand.getModels();

        modelsAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, modelsArr);

        modelsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        modelSpinner.setAdapter(modelsAdapter);

        modelSpinner.setSelection(modelsAdapter.getPosition(camera.getModel()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> a) {} 
}

);
```

Hope to be helpful.